# Load faster when using conditional success callback based on Ajax Response

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, html, web

I'm using AJAX to transfer data(text, link, img link) from server to front-end in JSON format.
Every data is an individual product and can be classified into one of the categories.

e.g. I want different layout(CSS) for different categories of product. Suppose there're only shoes, clothes, and Shorts. The layout of these 3 categories:

- Shoes: Larger title(100px), white font-color
- Clothes: Medium title(80px), black font-color
- Shorts: Small title(50px), green font-color

To make this happen, I define new variables "category_id" at server to identify the product category and put if else function inside the AJAX success function:
(if this item is shoes, category_id is 1. For clothes, the category_id is 2, and the category_id is 3 for shorts.)

Inside the js:

```
 $.ajax({  
            url:'http://localhost:8080/',
            dataType:'json',
            type:'get',
            success: function(result){
                   console.log(result);
                   $("#product_title").html(result.title);  
                   $("#product_img").attr("src",result.imageURL);
                    console.log(result.category_id);
                        if(result.category_id == 1){
                            $("#product_title").css("font-size","100px")
                            $("#product_title").css("color","white")
                        }
                        else if(result.category_id ==2){
                            $("#product_title").css("font-size","80px")
                            $("#product_title").css("color","black")
                        }
                        else{
                            $("#product_title").css("font-size","50px")
                            $("#product_title").css("color","green") 
                        }},
```

It actually did what I want, however it load so slow especially if I have over 4 categories.
I know the conditional statement slower the loading speed, but don't know how to improve it....

I'm thinking that is that possible to create some template to define the stuff inside the if else function first to make it load faster? or any better way?

Comment: The response of ajax call might not be correct. Could you paste the content of `result`?

Comment: Use `var $product_title = $("#product_title");` at the start of the function, then use the variable for further calls. You can also use classes to change the style, as opposed to manually setting CSS properties. However if your page is that slow, something else must be the problem.

Comment: try using switch statement